# RSA key pair with pass phrase (AES-128-CBC or AES-256-CBC)

Tags: c#, encryption

I have been trying to generate a RSA key  pair with passphrase in PEM format

Nuget-SSHKeygenerator- can generate keys but no symmetric encryption code for private key passphrase
Chilkat - has what I was looking for but paid
Bouncycastle - can generate keys but no symmetric encryption code found so far for private key
(found JceOpenSSLPKCS8EncryptorBuilder java library but the library is not in C#)

RSACryptoServiceProvider - didnt find anything so far. tried CspParameters . doc says it is for with smartcard-based CSPs.

Comment: so... what is your _question_? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Rephrasing the question. How do I generate  RSA key pair and add a passphrase to the private key in PEM format ?

Comment: i strongly recommend you actually ***do*** read the articles i've linked to. and then, afterwards, to ***edit*** your question to include more details.

Comment: Smart cards there are 8,16,32, and 64 bit address and data.  So you have to make sure you are using the correct address/data mode to unlock/lock cards.  My normal recommendations is to unlock card in windows using a file explorer.  The windows driver will do the unlocking and is smarter than your c# code in determining the address and data size.  Once card is unlocked you can then use c# code to read/write card to get the address and data size correct.  Then you can attempt to lock/unlock the card using the correct address data size.  It is hard to unlock a card not knowing the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you generate a RSA private key in that is protected with AES-128 encryption. This uses Chilkat library (paid license). I am posting for those who want to use a paid license. I am yet to find a way to write this without a paid license. This generate a private key with openSSH format(.PEM)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Chilkat.SshKey key = new Chilkat.SshKey();
        int numBits;
        int exponent;
      
        numBits = 4096; //this is the key size for RSA 
        exponent = 65537;
        success = key.GenerateRsaKey(numBits, exponent);
        if (success != true)

        string exportedKey;
        bool exportEncrypted;
        //  Export with encryption to OpenSSH private key format:
        key.Password = "password1!"; // this is the passphrase
        
        exportEncrypted = true;
        exportedKey = key.ToOpenSshPrivateKey(exportEncrypted);
        success = key.SaveText(exportedKey, "privkey_openssh_encrypted.pem");


        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");

    }
```